# Implement django-filter MultipleModelChoiceField for reverse relationship lookup?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have been using django-filters for one of my projects. As per documentation I have implemented a Product filter(for colours and material) for my product models. But after many tries I still cannot implement reverse look for product sizes which is in another table ProductSize.

**`models.py`**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    product_color = models.ForeignKey(Colour,related_name='productcolor')
    product_material=models.ForeignKey(Material)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

class ProductSize(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey('Product',related_name='details')
    value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stock= models.IntegerField(default=1)
    items_sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.value 

class Colour(models.Model):
    colour=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    colour_code=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %self.colour

class Material(models.Model):
    material=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %self.material
```

**`filters.py`**

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    product_material=django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Material.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
    product_color=django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Colour.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields=['product_color','product_material']
```

**`views.py`**

```
def product_view(request):
    product=Product.objest.all()
    f = ProductMaterialFilter(request.GET, queryset=product)
    context={'filter':f,}
    return render(request,'product.html',context)
```

Django Version:

```
django versions==1.10.8
django-filter==1.1.0
```

I need to know the steps for size filtering by 'value' of `ProductSize` models for `ProductFilter`.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5weD7.png).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `value = models.CharField(max_length=50)` stand for size? This is poor data design I think...

Comment: Please tell me how better the design can be considering stock of product to be updated for a particular size.

Comment: I mad fast update. Question is about filtering, and not db design.

Comment: Have a look on https://github.com/andilabs/filters-demo

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Colour(models.Model):
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    colour_code = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %self.colour


class Material(models.Model):
    material = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' %self.material


class Size(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=4)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.value


class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    product_color = models.ForeignKey(Colour,related_name='productcolor')
    product_material = models.ForeignKey(Material)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ({}, {})".format(self.product_name, self.product_color, self.product_material)


class Stock(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', related_name='details')
    size = models.ForeignKey('Size')
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    items_sold = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{product_name}({material}, {color}) @size: {size}, available {available} out of: {stock}".format(
            product_name=self.size.value,
            material=self.product.product_material.material,
            color=self.product.product_color.colour,
            size=self.size.value,
            available=self.stock-self.items_sold,
            stock=self.stock
        )
```

filters.py

```
import django_filters
from django import forms

from products.models import Material, Colour, Stock, Size


class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    product__product_material = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Material.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
    product__product_color = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Colour.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )

    size = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        queryset=Size.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ['product__product_color', 'product__product_material', 'size']
```

demo:

https://github.com/andilabs/filters-demo

Comment: I like your design. But simply thats not possible in my case as its already in production and the change of this scale will need changes in  codebase for many application ex. cart,orders,cms etc . May be I should try writing custom logic in the views to let size filtering possible. Thanks a lot for your time and suggestion. I will try to design better for my upcoming projects to avoid such hurdles.